# How to get posts filtered by custom field that is post object type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I want to get posts of an specific post type where those have custom field with type of post type.

I have post type named "tour", and tour post type has custom field named "country" that its type is Post Object.

The query for get all tours that their country is "Turkey":

```
$located_tours = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'tour',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'key'       => 'country',
        'title'     => 'Turkey',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    )
));
```

But this query return all tours without any filtering on Country

Anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `meta_query` [expects nested arrays](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters), so it's not:

```
'meta_query'  => array(
    'key'    => THE_KEY,
    'value'  => THE_VALUE,
),
```

but:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => THE_KEY,
        'value'   => THE_VALUE,
    ),
),
```

*Note that `compare` isn't necessary in your case as its default value is `=`.*

Anyway, you have a conceptual mistake here. If you are using [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) and your `country` custom field type is `Post Object`, the value for this field stored in the database is not `title` but the related post `ID` (either your *Return Format* is `Post Object` or `Post ID`).

Something like that (in your `wp_postmeta`table):

[image: wp_postmeta detail]

So, you need to query by country's `ID`, not country's Title. You could use `get_page_by_title` to retrieve your desired country ID:

```
// Assuming your Country's CPT slug is 'country'
$country = get_page_by_title( 'Turkey', 'OBJECT', 'country' );

$tours_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'tour',
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'country',
            'value' => $country->ID
        )
    )
);

$located_tours = get_posts( $tours_args );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$tour_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'tour',        
    'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key'     => 'country',
        'value'   => 'Turkey',
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
   ),
);
$located_tours =  new WP_Query($tour_args);
```

Comment: Thanks @vrajesh but it still returns all posts