# Filter custom post types by Post Object Custom Field

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have post types named "tour" and "country".
"tour" post type has some custom fields and type of one of them is Post Object and filtered by Post Type "country".

Now I want to show tours filtered by a specific country, for example:

```
$located_tours = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => 3,
    'post_type'     => 'tour',
    'meta_key'      => 'country',
    'meta_value'    => 'turkey'
));
```

But the result for this query shows nothing.

I know "country" I have used as meta_key is an object, but how can I use it correctly in my query?

Anyone has any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get posts filtered by custom field that is post object type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807204/how-to-get-posts-filtered-by-custom-field-that-is-post-object-type)

Comment: is 'country' also the name of the custom field on the 'tour' post type? Make sure that the meta_key and meta_value exactly match the name of the field and the value of the field.